# JQuery Entering Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the effect that when my pages loads, my divs fly in one by one. At the moment the flying in effect works, but everything flys in at the same time, i would like for it come in one by one.

My code looks like this:

```
        <script>
            function animateEnter( object ){
                object = $("#"+object);
                object.css("left","1000px");
                object.animate({
                    left: "0px"
                });
            }
        </script>


        <div id="1"></div>
        <script>
           animateEnter("1");
        </script>
        <div id="2"></div>
        <script>
           animateEnter("1");
        </script>
        <div id="3"></div>
        <script>
           animateEnter("1");
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout`

```
function animateEnter(object, time){
   setTimeout(function(){
       object = $("#"+object);
       object.css("left","1000px");
       object.animate({
          left: "0px"
       });
     },
     time
   );
}
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/ZUBZR/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but no everything still comes in at the same time. The setinterval function doesn't seem to be working. Any other solutions?

Comment: @user3871965 Have you passed different `time` on each function call?

Comment: you mean increment the time variable ? No i haven't let me try.

Comment: @Codious-JR yes, and it means time in milliseconds, so 3 seconds = `time = 3000`

Comment: @Codious-JR added JSFiddel to answer with optimized code

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var count=0;
var delay=1000;
function animateEnter( object ){
                object = $("#"+object);
                object.css("left","1000px");
                fly(object);
            }
function fly(object){
    count++;
    setInterval(function(){
        $(object).animate({
                    left: "0px"
                },delay);
        },(count*delay));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks For the Response, but no everything still comes in at the same time.The setinterval function doesn't seem to be working. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

No need to work with timeouts or anything. Just use the `callback` function of the `animate` like this:

**HTML**:

```
<div>DIV 1</div>
<div>DIV 2</div>
<div>DIV 3</div>
<div>DIV 4</div>
<div>DIV 5</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
div {
    left: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    AnimateNext($("div"), 0);
});

function AnimateNext(divs, next) {
    if (next === divs.length) 
        return;

    $(divs[next]).animate({
        left: "0px"
    }, function () {
        next++;
        AnimateNext(divs, next);
    });
}
```

Working **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LMQeP/2/)**.